# How do cgo pass -Wall -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker

Tags: go, gcc, cgo

When use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc for cross compile. GOOS only support linux and do not support android.

```sh
CGO_ENABLED=1 CGO_CFLAGS CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm go build -o hello .
# After build generated hello file
file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=038c80350b7a0c9e72b10021c66c31c2dbb4df2c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

As you can see the output file hello with `dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3`. It can not run in android platform.

```sh
./hello
/system/bin/sh: ./hello: No such file or directory
```

In Android the interpreter should be `/system/bin/linker`. **My question is how to specific dynamic linker with cgo?**

As i searched in [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610103/how-do-you-cross-compile-elf-executables-for-android). the gcc has params like `gcc -o test test.c -Wall -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker`.

Comment: Try gomobile, it supports android

Answer (score 0):

you can enable cgo and send these flags to cgo from the comment above `import "C"` statement:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: --dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux.so.3
*/
import "C"

func main() {
}
```

Tell me if this work

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used NDK build for android.