# Unfamiliar linker switch "-dynamic-linker"

Tags: linker, clang

I have some (admittedly old) makefile that generates a command line of the form -

```
clang++  <...>  -Wl,-dynamic-linker  [..path..]/ld-2.19.so <...>
```

As far as I can see the `-dynamic-linker` switch is undocumented. It does *not* control the used linker (there's `-fuse-ld` for that), and I don't know what the pointed .so file does.

Anyone seen something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(dumping the answer here in case it is of use to others)

I couldn't find it in any docs, but it is mentioned in several SO answers ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617852/89706)) and in the output of `ld --help`.

This switch controls the linux *loader* (a.k.a., dynamic linker) used to load needed shared-libs into the program. The pointed .so is an alternative to the shipped loader, [ld.so](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).